# Cisco VPN client failed to enable virtual adaptor

Tags: windows-7, cisco-vpn-client

I'm trying to connect to a server using Cisco VPN client 5.0.07.0290 on windows 7 but while it's trying to secure the communications channel it comes up with an error 'Failed to enable Virtual Adaptor'.

Can anyone shed any light on the problem?

Comment: I am facing the same problem Richard. Disabling ICS did not help. Could you update your question to let people know that (if) it did not work for you as well?

Comment: Had the same problem on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the Internet Connection Sharing service is not running.

[Found Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sreekanth/entry/reason_442_failed_to_enable)

---

Summary extract:

In Summary(or for some reason the above link is broken) this worked for me,

1. Start Menu
2. Network
3. Click on Network Sharing
4. Click on Manage Networks in the new window opened
5. Right Click on Cisco Adapter and click on Diaognise.
6. Reset the Network adapter
7. Now it says there is limited connectivity.Ignore it and restart the machine.
8. Now try connecting to VPN.Thats all.Now you are connected.

Comment: I re-installed my vpn-client, getting the same error as Richard and this does not work for me. The ICS is already diabled

Answer (score 2):

This is probably very late for [Richard](https://superuser.com/users/76482/richard), but I am writing this for the benefit of other users who navigate to this forum due to its popularity.

First-off, I am using the `Cisco VPN v 5.0.07..0440` on `64-bit Windows`

In my case the 442 error was spawned by the display name of the virtual adapter getting modified in the registry after a VPN re-install (to resolve a separate issue).

The steps to fix this problem are as follows:

1. Hit `windows+R` type `regedit` in the Search field and hit enter.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA`
3. Find the String Value called `DisplayName`
4. Right click and select `Modify` from the context menu.
5. In Value data, remove `@oemX.inf,%CVirtA_Desc%;`. The Value data should only contain `Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows`.
6. Click Ok.
7. Close Registry Editor.
8. Retry your Cisco VPN Client connection.

Comment: This solutions is taken from https://supertekboy.com/2013/10/19/cisco-vpn-on-windows-8-1-reason-442-failed-to-enable-virtual-adapter/.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you check in network and sharing center/change adapter settings if the cisco virtual adapter is not disabled.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I've already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was a software named Phantom Camera Control (PCC) Version 3.3.781.0. This software has a additional device driver and network service. After uninstalling it VPN connection works fine.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your problem sounds like it was specific to an obscure app.  Do you think it will apply generally to other people with the same problem?